# URL rewrite or reverse proxy for appending a string in request URL - OHS/Apache webserver

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, scim, oim

We are dealing with a SCIM based requirement for provisioning a target system from OIM.
OIM's SCIM endpoints are in url pattern /idaas/im/scim/v1/endpoint.
While, target system appends /scim/endpoint on it's own. So, post configuration, it becomes, `/idaas/im/scim/endpoint`.

This requires us to rewrite the URL on OHS webserver with following rewrite rule:
Rewrite Rule `^/idaas/im/scim/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ "/idaas/im/scim/v1/$1" [R=301,NC]`

This works with Postman, but fails in actual scenario as redirect request will remove the request headers.

Tried Proxy mode and Reverse Proxy using ProxyPass, but, nothing worked.
Anyone has any idea for proxying or redirecting without losing request header from `/idaas/im/scim/endpoint` to `/idaas/im/scim/v1/endpoint`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ,It should be reconciliation from Target to OIM, it can't be provisioning from target.

Comment: From a target system perspective, it's provisioning.

Comment: One can provision to a target system from OIM and not vice-versa,in the other case its called reconciliation not provisioning ,the `to` and `from` matters ,thats what my point was :)

Comment: What error are you getting?